# Laravel 8 Installation - npm install && npm run dev Errors

Tags: php, node.js, laravel

I am getting an errors while writing the command `npm install && npm run dev` in Laravel.
Here is the errors

```
WARN engine sass@1.57.1: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0",                                                                                                              npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperj                                                                                                              s/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21                                                                                                              .1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
loadDep:vue2-dropzone → a ▄ ╢█████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine vue-trumbowyg@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":">= 6.9.0","npm":">= 3.10.8"} (                                                                                                              loadDep:vue2-dropzone → g ▄ ╢█████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine @coreui/coreui@2.1.16: wanted: {"node":">= 8.7","npm":">= 5"} (curre                                                                                                              npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-197-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-meta                                                                                                              data.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package                                                                                                              -metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.                                                                                                              js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-packag                                                                                                              e-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package                                                                                                              -metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fe                                                                                                              tch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at                                                                                                              :
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/market2/growex2/npm-debug.log
```

I need to install node.js in Laravel.

Comment: Try to update your node version

Comment: did u read the first line? `WARN engine sass@1.57.1: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first line of your console error, you can see that it says you need an upgraded version of node.

Your node version is 8.10.0, and you need node version 12.0.0 or superior to install sass.

I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to change your node version and in case you have projects using an older node version you can just switch versions this way easily.